# Does firebug not (always) duplicate repeated identical console.logs?

Tags: javascript, firebug

I always thought that firebug would send to the console content whenever the JavaScript encountered `console.log('send this');`

Then, I was messing around with jQuery's hover() method (something like `$(".myDiv").hover(function () {...},function () {...console.log('leave');});`, and couldn't figure out why an event was only happening once.  Turns out it appears that firebug will only display the first occurrence of an identical console.log.

Then I added an identical `console.log('leave');` after the first one, and not only did it display twice, but each time I hovered out, it displayed twice again.

Then, instead of duplicating the second console.log, I put a loop around it.  This time it displayed only once, and wouldn't display on subsequent times I hovered out.

What is going on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a new feature added in Firebug 1.12 called [console grouping](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=4979).

To disable it (requires version 1.12.1) :

- Go to "about:config"
- Promise you'll be careful
- look for "extensions.firebug.console.groupLogMessages"
- double-click on the option => the value is set to false

See also:

- https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Preferences
- http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=6703

Florent

Comment: Thank you.  I personally do not feel this "feature" should be the default.

Comment: IMO this feature can be enabled by default, but should be easily disableable in Firebug options menu, not global browser preferences.

Comment: @s3m3n It is now. See my answer to [How do I disable firefox console from grouping duplicate output?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59935855/1744774)